# Layer-backed NSImageView corrupts it's image after entering full screen mode

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, calayer, nsimageview

I have a NSImageView with turned on layer backing on it in IB.
ImageView's image is generating as Quick Look preview. If view is resizing to a bigger size I generate  new preview.

All works fine until my App enters full screen mode. After that my code obtains new quick look preview and sets it to imageView. On imageView resizing image corrupts: it creates same image above and below. "Below" image works fine on resize - thats what I want, but "above" image doesn't resize - just goes up or down on resize and has very strange layout behavior...

Here are some screenshots for better understanding of image corrupting:
[image: on reducing height]

[image: on enlarging height]

After exiting from fullscreen - problems disappear)
If I turn off layer backing on this view - problems also disappear)

Seems this is cocoa bug but maybe someone had such problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've researched my problem a little and found very interesting thing: this bug reproduces only if imageView's size is bigger than 2000 pixels... continue researching)))

Comment: Seems I found a problem: I forgot about max size of Layer-backed view - 2000 pixels. That's what a problem... searching for answer)